# Does the shat"z or congregant have to say the correct Song of the Day?

Tags: mistakes, shir-shel-yom

Let's say on Tuesday a congregant or the Shat"z said the Shabbat *mizmor*, accidentally. Does either one need to repeat it saying the correct one for that day of the week?

I know that this is "just Tehillim", and one can say any Tehillim at the end of tefilla. (I've seen many shuls add one or two esp. *Shir Hama'lot*. It's usually done for the ill or so that someone can say Kaddish, etc.) But, perhaps because one introduced the mizmor of the day with the phrase, e.g.:

"Today is the 3rd day of the week which on it the Levi'im would say in the Bet Hamikdash"

And then, he says the wrong mizmor. In a sense, it seems to be a misleading statement, perhaps, as the Levi'im did not say the Shabbat mizmor that day.

Comment: Is this any different from the general question "Is saying Shir Shel Yom every day obligatory?"

Comment: I vaguely recall something about how the main thing is the introductory sentence, in order that we mention Shabbos every day of the week. I've got one of Rabbi Reisman's CD sets on Tehillim in my car (and that's where I think I heard it), so I'll bring that back up in the rotation and if I hear an answer sometime in the next months' worth of commuting, I'll try to come back with an answer. :)

Comment: @DoubleAA That's an interesting question, but I think it's different than mine. If we assumed that it is obligatory, or, for that matter, even if it's optional, but you said it, are you obligated to say the right one?

Comment: Umm... If I accidentally read Kohelet on Purim do I fulfill my obligation? I don't understand what you are thinking, assuming Shir Shel Yom is indeed an obligation. If you don't read the obligatory thing then what have you done?

Comment: Cf. Arachin 11b: “The song of the day is ‘To Hashem is the land and its fill.’ ‘And He brought upon them their iniquity’ is Wednesday’s song! Rather, it was a lamentation which fell into their mouth.” I could hear this Gemara going either way, which is why I’m not posting it as an answer, but perhaps someone says something on it which is relevant.

Comment: @DoubleAA Huh?? There is such a thing as *b'dieved*.

Comment: Surely there is. How might it apply here? Would Kohelet work Bedieved? Why might one think some other chapter of Tehillim could work Bedieved here? I don't understand

Comment: @DoubleAA the mitzva deoraisa is for the Leviyim to sing, not to sing anything in particular.  Maybe shir shel yom is modeled after that.

Comment: @Heshy then we were all Yotzei with Ashrei

Comment: Cf.+ Sanhedrin 101 הקורא פסוק בזמנו מביא טובה לעולם